# cpupower command output shows POLL column as 0

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, monitoring, cpu, cpu-usage

I have to monitor CPU cores of my server for the Idle C states. I'm using the cpupower linux tool to monitor the idle states of the CPU.

Below is the output the command `'cpupower monitor -m Idle_Stats'`.

My question is why the column POLL shows 0.0 always?

```
    | Idle_Stats
 CPU| POLL | C1   | C1E  | C3   | C6
   0|  0.00|  6.00|  0.01|  0.08| 90.39
   6|  0.00|  5.29|  0.12|  0.32| 89.70
   1|  0.00|  1.15|  0.12|  0.13| 92.80
   7|  0.00|  6.49|  0.11|  0.60| 89.73
   2|  0.00|  1.47|  0.08|  0.54| 94.04
   8|  0.00| 15.61|  0.12|  0.31| 81.26
   3|  0.00|  1.23|  0.09|  0.14| 95.90
   9|  0.00|  6.53|  0.26|  0.94| 86.41
   4|  0.00| 10.14|  0.01|  0.07| 88.01
  10|  0.00|  2.15|  0.99|  0.87| 90.90
   5|  0.00|  1.61|  0.06|  0.82| 94.35
  11|  0.00|  4.52|  0.24|  0.26| 91.90
```

I expected to see some value under POLL column.